# Notify Spotify App with NodeJS server

Tags: node.js, spotify

I have a NodeJS server running on Heroku, and I want to send some data to my local Spotify app (which is not online since Spotify wont accept any new apps currently).

I tested this with a local NodeJS server as follows and it worked perfectly.

I send the arguments in my NodeJS server using:

```
open("spotify:app:app_name:some:arguments:here");
```

I catch the arguments in my local Spotify App using:

```
models.application.addEventListener('arguments', function() {
    if (models.application.arguments[0] == "some") {
        ...
    }
    else if (models.application.arguments[1] == "arguments") {
        ...
    }
});
```

However, now that I have my NodeJS server online, the arguments don't get passed anymore, I think because the open(..) function doesn't work properly anymore.

(Note: My NodeJS server is running fine, I think it's just the open(..) function that fails)

EDIT: I also tried this opener: https://github.com/domenic/opener but to no avail..

Any tips?

Comment: Are we talking about the official Spotify desktop application or something else? And if it's the official one, what platform are you on?

Comment: No this is a custom App

Comment: I think that is what @WanderNauta is actually suggesting here - a third party app in the Desktop client, using the [Spotify Apps API](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/). Is this correct?

Comment: Ah, yes I'm using the Spotify Apps API to create my own app in the Desktop client. But I think I have a solution already, though I doubt its the best solution out there. I'm calling a hyperlink ("spotify:app:app_name:arguments:go:here") in my NodeJS server, that passes some arguments.

Comment: Got it! I just want you to be aware that the Apps platform no longer accept new contributions. Read more: https://developer.spotify.com/news-stories/2014/03/24/closure-of-spotify-apps-submissions/

Comment: Ok, this seemed to work locally, but not anymore when I pushed my NodeJS server online. (note I still have my app running locally since spotify no longer accepts contributions)